# MySQLSyntaxError inserting into MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, insert

I would like to insert data into the MySQL database that I am using.I get this [ERROR](http://pastebin.com/GDr9KV8j).This is my code:

```
public boolean insertValues(String gisuniqkey,String objtype,String objkey,String lat,String lng)
{
    int rc=-1;
    try {
        if(conn==null)
        {
            System.out.println("The connection was not initialized.");
            return false;
        }   
        Statement st=(Statement) conn.createStatement();
        //lots of String concatenation,very expensive...BAD...use StringBuilder instead
        String sql="Insert into ZMAPERP_GIS_DB (GISUNIQKEY,OBJTYPE,OBJKEY,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE) values("+gisuniqkey+","+objtype+","+objkey+","+lat+","+lng+");";
        System.out.println(sql);
        rc=st.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rc>0?true:false;
}
```

Comment: You are missing inverted commas

Comment: @Strawberry inverted commas but where,what would be the correct version of this string

Comment: I would recommend changing to a PreparedStatement rather than building up your query string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the insert statement should be like this, Use single quotes around the values:

```
"Insert into ZMAPERP_GIS_DB (GISUNIQKEY,OBJTYPE,OBJKEY,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE) values('"+gisuniqkey+"','"+objtype+"','"+objkey+"','"+lat+"','"+lng+"');";
```

**Edit**

Try it yourself in a command. What will work:

Option 1:

```
INSERT INTO ZMAPERP_GIS_DB (GISUNIQKEY,OBJTYPE,OBJKEY,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE)
VALUES(asdasd,asdasd,asdasd,asdasd);
```

Option 2:

```
INSERT INTO ZMAPERP_GIS_DB (GISUNIQKEY,OBJTYPE,OBJKEY,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE)
VALUES('asdasd','asdasd','asdasd','asdasd');
```

I would think that option 2 will work

**Edit 2**

But as mention in the comment. Using the prepare statement is recommended. Because this is open for sql injections

Reference:

- [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
- [JDBC PreparedStatement Example – Insert A Record](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/)

Comment: Why use single quotes?

Comment: Yes. Because otherwise it will not be recognized as a sql command

Comment: It's really worthwhile to mention that he should consider prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should use PreparedStatements to avoid problems with building query strings.

```
    PreparedStatement statement = null;

    String insertSql = "Insert into ZMAPERP_GIS_DB (GISUNIQKEY,OBJTYPE,OBJKEY,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE) values (?,?,?,?,?)";

    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    statement = conn.prepareStatement(insertSql);

    statement.setString(1, gisuniqkey);
    statement.setString(2, objtype);
    statement.setString(3, objkey);
    statement.setString(4, lat);
    statement.setString(5, lng);

    con.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql="Insert into ZMAPERP_GIS_DB (GISUNIQKEY,OBJTYPE,OBJKEY,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE) values('"+gisuniqkey+"','"+objtype+"','"+objkey+"','"+lat+"','"+lng+"');";
```

Although, I would suggest you inject variable values using prepared statement.